# How to count or replace all matching words between { } or [ ] in javascript with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to process a file with may sentences in javascript. And there are some special sentences that are wrapped in brackets [ ] or { }. And between this brackets the word can occure multiple times. So to find a word at all I tried first:

```
RegExp('\\bmyword\\b', 'g');
```

But how do I insert that the words need to be inside the brackets and that anything can be between the brackets and words?
And if I'm looking for 500 words in about 10k sentences, how can I speed it up? Should I then use pattern?

Comment: Are you replacing these words with something else? Or plainly extracting?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do but I think something like this will work `[{\[][^}\]]*\b(for)\b[^{\[]*[}\]]` [example](https://regex101.com/r/AGqGSc/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's extracting and counting. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it is now much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may extract all substrings between `{}` and `[]` with `/\[[^[\]]*]|{[^{}]*}/g` pattern and look for the words you need inside those matches only.

If you search for `word` in `word [myword word hisword word] and word here, {word myword theirword} too.`, you expect `3` as output:

```js
var s = "word [myword word hisword word] and word here, {word myword theirword} too.",
    keyword = "word",
    results = 0,
    rx = /\[[^[\]]*]|{[^{}]*}/g;

// COUNTING
var matches = s.match(rx);
var rxWord = new RegExp("\\b" + keyword + "\\b", "g");
for (var x of matches) {
  results += x.match(rxWord).length;
}
console.log(results)

// REPLACING
console.log( s.replace(rx, function($0) { return $0.replace(rxWord, '$&_ID'); }) );
```

The `\[[^[\]]*]|{[^{}]*}` pattern - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mronV4/1) - matches:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^[\]]*` - any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `|` - or
- `{` - a `{` char
- `[^{}]*` - any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor. Looks pretty complicated. I have to learn more about regex. One more question. Maybe later I have to append and ID to a word. How would that look like? Your solution looks very nice and clean. Damn that would a replace right and I said in the first response no, sorry.

Comment: @Ajay If you need to replace the `rxWord` matches inside the matches found with `rx`, you may use `s.replace(rx, function($0) { return $0.replace(rxWord, '$&_ID'); } );` where `$&_ID` is the match value (`$&`) and and appended substring (here, `_ID`).

Comment: holy Moses, so much new stuff Thank you very much :) Do you think it makes any significant performance difference if it's like your solution or is it maybe worth refactoring it?